# Display in V-Select in Vue

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a problem displaying the values in `v-select`. The value to display should be the `name` in `type: { id: 2, name: "Certificate 2" }`, but it's appearing blank.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jtan80813/pen/XWXLBKb)

```
addDocument() {
  this.form.documents.push({
    document_type: null,
    file: null
  });
},

removeDocument(document) {
  this.form.documents.splice(this.form.documents.indexOf(document), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `v-select` has its `v-model` bound to `document.id`, but the document type is actually stored in `document.type.id`. Also, `addDocument()` should initialize this value:

```html
<template>
  <!-- BEFORE -->
  <!-- <v-select v-model="document.id"></v-select> -->

  <v-select v-model="document.type.id"></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    addDocument() {
      this.form.documents.push({
        document_type: null,
        file: null,

        // initial document type
        type: {
          id: 2,
          name: "Certificate 2"
        },
      });
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjGgxGe?editors=1010)